# Can element selector be declared in external css?

Tags: css, css-selectors

The following selector is declared in external stylesheet

```
p:first-letter
{
  color: red;
}
```

But it doesn't make the first letter in `<p>` element turn red. It does work when this is declared in internal css.

Comment: And you're absolutely sure the external stylesheet is being loaded correctly?

Comment: The other css rules work correctly from the external file? Maybe something else override the rule? try `p:first-letter{color:red !important;}` to find out if something like this happens. Also use firebug, or make a live demo at http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://jsbin.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can.

What you wrote should work just fine; are you sure you are linking to the external stylesheet correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly fine for me in Firefox 3.6.x:

**external-selector.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="external-selector.css" type="text/css">
        <style type="text/css">
            p { color: blue; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Paragraph!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**external-selector.css**

```
p:first-letter {
    color: red;
}
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: I have used html 4.01 doctype could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, and after over an hour of messing with Firefox I figured out that it's the InvisibleHand addon that is causing this problem for me.  When I disabled it, the problem went away.

I have emailed their info email address asking them to fix the bug.

Answer (score 0):

it seems any other CSS is conflicting.

try if it work

```
p:first-letter
{
 color: red !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem described here. I knew the external stylesheet was being applied because I could see other styles being applied. After reading Heptite's answer I decided I'd try updating Firefox. This fixed the problem.

So, perhaps this was a bug that got fixed in the latest Firefox (v39.0)